# Is the Weierstrass M-Test an equivalence?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Given $g_n(x)= \frac{nx}{1+n^2 x}$, $g_n : [0,1] \to \mathbb R, n \in \mathbb N, n\geq 1$,  I am trying to show that $g_n$ converges uniformly. I have shown that it converges pointwise to $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$, with $g(x)=0$. Now I wish to show that it converges uniformly.

I know how to do this using the epsilon definition, however I tried applying the M test, which states that if 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ||g_n||_\infty < \infty$$ then the sequence converges uniformly. However, for this sequence, this yields me with $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty ||\frac{nx}{1+n^2x}||_\infty =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sup_{x\in [0,1]} \left|\frac{nx}{1+n^2x}\right|=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left|\frac n {1+n^2} \right|.$$ To my knowledge, this is divergent.

On the contrary, we were told that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} ||f_n - f||_\infty = 0 \iff f\text{ is uniformly convergent.}$$ Using this definition here, however, yields $$\lim_{n\to\infty}||\frac{nx}{1+n^2x}-0||_\infty = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{1+n^2}=0.$$

I have tried searching yet am unable to clarify where my mistake here lies. Is the M test not an equivalence? Or am I merely mistaken?

Comment: Are you trying to show $(g_n)_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$ converges uniformly, or $\sum_{n=1}^\infty g_n$ converges uniformly?

Comment: @ClementYung I'm trying to show that $(g_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges uniformly - I mistakenly thought that the M test meant that the sequence will converge. However, I was taught that if the M test holds, ie the summ is <inf, then the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n$ converges absolutely and uniformly to a function $f:D\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Also noting the answer, can I ask for an explanation of what this test actually does then? It was my understanding that this means that the sum of $f_n$ converges to $f$. Is this not the case? @ClementYung

Comment: [Weierstrass M-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) asserts that for each function $g_n$, if $\|g_n\|_\infty < M_n$ for some constant $M_n > 0$, and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty M_n < \infty$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty g_n$ converges uniformly to some function $g$. It seems like you've mixed up the convergence of $g_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty g_n$ here.

Comment: Thank you again. So just for clarity - $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} g_n$ converges uniformly to some function $g$. But this function, $g$ is not the same as the function that the functionsequence $g_n$ converges to uniformly? (assuming $g_n$ conv. uniformly)

Comment: Yes. In fact, if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty g_n$ converges uniformly, then we must have $g_n \to 0 $ uniformly, as $M_n \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you are asking if the following implication holds:
$$(g_n) \  \text{converges uniformly} \implies\Sigma||g_n||_\infty<\infty $$

To see that this is false take $\forall x\ \ :g_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}$.